# Firefox and Chrome flexbox different behaviour overflow-y with nested blocks

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

*My web page sample (looks different in Chrome and Firefox):*

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Firefox vs Chrome</title>

  </head>

  <body style="margin:  0px;">
    <div id="root" style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;height:  100vh;">
      <header style="background: orange;flex: 0 0 auto;height: 200px;">Header</header>

      <div id="sub-1" style="flex: 1 1 auto;background: blue;display:  flex;">
        <div id="sub-2" style="overflow: auto;display: flex;flex: 1 1 auto;">
          <div id="content" style="height: 2000px;flex: 1;">
             Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Result in Chrome (as expected):**

[image]

**Result in Firefox (bug???)**

[image]

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `#sub-1`. Fixes the problem in FF and Edge. https://jsfiddle.net/dr461h6m/2/ (See my answer in the dupe for details. In particular, see the *Browser Rendering Notes*.)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem